# How to convert number to string in JavaScript when user inputs a number

Tags: javascript

```
let num = prompt("enter a number");
let foo = num.split("").map(item => parseInt(item, 10));
let fig = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let arr = [
  "zero",
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "four",
  "five",
  "six",
  "seven",
  "eight",
  "nine"
];
fig[0] = arr[0];
fig[1] = arr[1];
fig[2] = arr[2];
// let filteredNum = foo.filter(number => fig.includes(number));
// console.log(filteredNum);
// console.log(fig[0]);
// console.log(fig[1]);
// console.log(fig[2]);
```

I need help with this, I have an array of numbers (0 - 9). I provided a prompt for a user to input a number, such that that when the user inputs 1, it prints out a string 'one', if the user inputs 34, it prints out string of three four.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to check that the string is a number?

```
const num = prompt("enter a number");

const arr = [ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four",
            "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" ];

let foo = [];

if(!isNaN(num)) {
  foo = num.split('').map(n => arr[n]).join(' ');
}

console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following

```js
let num = prompt("enter a number");
let foo = num.split("").map(item => parseInt(item, 10));

let arr = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"];

console.log(foo.reduce((a,c) => a + " " + arr[c], ""));
```

Please see, there is no need of `fig` as you already have index of `arr` to match the numeric value of string

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to check if an alphabet or non-number(special characters) is inputted by the user, an error should be display?

Comment: You can check for `isNaN()` or `parseInt()` and then check for NaN first. If its NaN, then its invalid and return else continue with logic

Comment: something like this:
```if(isNaN(foo)) {
}
```

Comment: @Perorary -  This one covers all the cases - `if(isNaN(parseInt(foo, 10))) { }`

Comment: I'm a little confused what the '10' is doing inside of the parseInt(), can you explain, please?

Comment: It is Radix - An integer between 2 and 36 that represents the radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems) of the above mentioned string. A radix of 10 indicates to convert from a decimal number. For more details - refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have asked you that. Actually, this is my first time asking on StackOverflow : )

Comment: I decided to add a '-' to the string but I don't want it to show after the last string
https://jsfiddle.net/ht3qmb46/

Comment: @Peoray - You could ask the one who has posted the answer or could let me know the name, so that I can help

Comment: Oh wow, Index, totally forgot about it. Thank you so much. Is there any way to contact you aside here?

Comment: @Peoray - Yes. You can drop me an email at nikhil.agw@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your number into string and use an object as a dictionary, :

```js
const num = prompt("enter a number");
const dict = {
  "0": "zero",
  "1": "one",
  "2": "two",
  "3": "three",
  "4": "four",
  "5": "five",
  "6": "six",
  "7": "seven",
  "8": "eight",
  "9": "nine"
}
const res = `${num}`.split('').map(e => dict[e]).join(' ');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `reducer` is really required here. This is a simple logic and can be achieved using a simple loop too.

```js
let num = prompt("enter a number");
let foo = num.split("").map(item => parseInt(item, 10));

let arr = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"];

var inputStr = '';
foo.forEach((num)=>{
  inputStr +=  arr[num] + ' ';
});
console.log(inputStr);
```

Or you can even use a one liner like this:

```js
let num = prompt("enter a number");
let arr = ["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"];

let foo = num.split("").map(item => arr[parseInt(item, 10)]).join(' ');

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: I decided to add a '-' to the string but I don't want it to show after the last string. Here is JS fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/ht3qmb46/

Comment: @Peoray stop asking for everything here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for getting single digits (string as an iterable) and map the word if exists. If not take the value.

Later join the array with space.

```js
var numbers = prompt("enter a number"),
    array = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];

console.log(Array.from(numbers, i => array[i] || i).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

## Code :

```js
console.log(prompt("enter a number").split``.map(_ => ~~_).reduce((_, i) => `${_} ${"zero one two three four five six seven eight nine".split` `[i]}`, ``));
```

## Methods :

This uses `map` and `reduce`

## Explanation :

```
console.log(                /*begin console.log*/
    prompt(                 /*take input*/
        'enter a number'.   /*input text*/
            split``.        /*split at every single char*/
            map(            /*map over all elements of the array*/
                _ => ~~_).  /*convert to number and reduce to integer*/
                reduce(     /*begin reducing the array to one value*/
                    (_,i)=> /*parameters*/
                    `${_} ${'zero one two three four five six seven eight nine'.split` `[i]}`
                , ''))
// the last part writes value of _ and then creates a string (0-9) and splits at 
//space and then selects the value depending on i
```